# AttributeError: 'tuple' object has no attribute 'copy'

Tags: python, copy, attributeerror

Can any one explain this error message to me?

```
# make a copy or hand is destroyed by your test
remaining = hand.copy()
```

Result:

```
AttributeError: 'tuple' object has no attribute 'copy'
```

I can do this:

```
remaining = copy.copy(hand)
```

which returns this:

```
(None, {hand...})
```

Which throws off what i'm trying to accomplish because the function is returning False when it searches the None return value.

This is the function that creates the hand:

```
def deal_hand(n):
"""
Returns a random hand containing n lowercase letters.
At least n/3 the letters in the hand should be VOWELS.

Hands are represented as dictionaries. The keys are
letters and the values are the number of times the
particular letter is repeated in that hand.

n: int >= 0
returns: dictionary (string -> int)
"""
hand={}
num_vowels = n / 3

for i in range(num_vowels):
    x = VOWELS[random.randrange(0,len(VOWELS))]
    hand[x] = hand.get(x, 0) + 1

for i in range(num_vowels, n):    
    x = CONSONANTS[random.randrange(0,len(CONSONANTS))]
    hand[x] = hand.get(x, 0) + 1

return hand
```

EDIT:
I changed hand further along the way and created a tuple out of it instead of a dictionary.  Thanks!

Comment: The error message is because tuples don't have a `copy` method.  Why are you trying to call `copy` on a tuple?

Comment: Because I want to run tests on hand and not destroy it

Comment: It would be better if we had more context for your situation. It is clear that you are trying to call copy() on a tuple, which is invalid because tuples don't have a method called `copy`. We don't know why you're trying to do that, though.

Comment: @ChrisSchell: What are you doing that you think will "destroy" it?  You can't destroy a tuple.

Comment: The `hand` that is returned from the method does not appear to be the same `hand` that you are trying to copy. Please provide the code in which you call `remaining = hand.copy()`.

Comment: If this is no longer a problem, and given that it seems unlikely that anyone else would find this useful, please delete the question rather than editing that in (you will have to unaccept the answer and ask that they delete it first).

Answer (score 2):

The error is very clear: You have a tuple, on which you try to call `copy`.

It seems that the object you have in `hand` is not the object you intended, but a tuple, instead.

Comment: Can you delete your answer so I can delete my question?  Thanks!